# Save the output of earlier tailed logs to a file?

Tags: grep, logs, tail

Is it possible to save the output of earlier tailed logs to a file?

Steps to Reproduce this issue:

1. `tail -f application.log`
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to end the logs
3. Save that output to a file now.

I am assuming an algorithm like this exists.

```
tail -f application.log | cat >> EOF > /tmp/greppedTMP
```

Comment: You've used `tail -f`, which continues until interrupted. Should we assume that you're "looking for something", and it's only when you spot it that you then want the last _N_ rows of the file? If so, can you quantify the "something" and the _N_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
tail -f application.log | tee -a /tmp/log
```

[tee](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) will save the STDIN to a file and also send it to STDOUT. (without `-a` it will overwrite any existing file).

Comment: Thank you. I finally understood the importance of tee command.

Comment: `tee` can be very useful. One way I often use it is to write to the kernel message buffer with `echo hello | sudo tee -a /dev/kmsg`